# Search box autocomplete

Tags: feature-request, search, search-box

So we have this search box:

[image]

The types of users that will use it, to name a few, will be **(A)** those who want to look for a solution or **(B)** those who want to answer some questions.

As a **(B)** user, I might type in [`intags:mine is:question`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) and go from there.

At times, I might look into all javascript questions that don't involve, let's say, angular (`[javascript] -[angular]`).

And so on. After an extensive usage, I get a pretty comprehensive list of scenarios I will personally use the search box for and SO already knows which queries I performed and how often.

As such, can we have a search history, ordered by most used queries so that, as I type something in the search box, or when I click on it, a dropdown appears showing at most 5 entries?

If anyone feels they don't want it because it'll bother them, then make it configurable in settings (Disable search history, Remove specific entries, Etc.)

Comment: **(A)** users should use Google or another context-sensitive search engine. The site search is really quite poor to look for solutions. But yeah, good feature request otherwise. Doing a quick search on meta.SE and meta.SO, I'm a little amazed I don't really see any previous requests for it, just a bunch of tag autocompletion requests. [This one is similar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38953/implement-google-like-autocomplete-on-searches).

Comment: Remark: on Chrome, on the full search page (`https://stackoverflow.com/search`), the past search entries are auto-completed as soon as I type a letter or two. Though I get it that you're looking for a native SE feature, this can serve as a workaround for the time being.