# Missing blue search-icon at the right side of the search-box?

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-declined, user-interface, search-box

I may be missing something, but I'm pretty sure the search line on the main page has this blue icon at the **right side** (of a magnify glass) - currently it is empty:

[image]

It may be minor, but I could hit it for refresh of the search - now I need to set the mouse on the search line, click it and then hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>...

It's gone for me both in Google Chrome and Internet Explorer - was it intentional?

**Edited**

This is how the blue icon on the right used to look like: [image]

(taken from [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/367245/search-box-autocomplete) question)

To avoid the discussion if this is a bug or not, adding the feature-request tag as this post goal was to bring it back.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I have seen a report in the last 6 to 8 weeks that argued that the search button that shows up there should always be visible (the call to action used to appear when the search box got focus). Maybe they misinterpreted that report and got rid of the button all together ...

Comment: My search fu is escaping me. I can't find said report anymore here nor on MSE. Maybe roomba got it. Yes, thay assumes I'm still sane and not dreaming up stuff.

Comment: So this will be fix? To who can I address with this? It may be minor but was easy to use for me

Comment: You have done what you need to do. In 6 to 8 hours the developer that is on bug duty will pick-up on the new reports. And then  hopefully find the regression and puts a new build out.

Comment: *"hit it for refresh of the search"* - that's pretty uncommon scenario if you ask me. What do you search and why do you need to refresh? To go to first page? I like how you make 2 clicks (click, hit enter) into 3 (**move mouse**, click, hit enter).

Comment: As I have a tag search and after some time I want to refresh to see new questions or activity (I know I could use the f5 but I with the mouse at some times). I don't want to move to first page but stay in the current tag (or tags) section

Comment: UI wise it's kinda weird to have two magnifying glasses in the same input anyway.

Comment: @Sinatr Not that I disagree with the theme of your comment, but moving the mouse is *not* a "click"

Comment: @dWinder May I suggest tagging this with [meta-tag:feature-request] to add this back?

Comment: But it'll be bad for people who don't have a keyboard.

Comment: I use a remote mouse so click the keyboard is extra move (as not by a desk) - and beside - pushing "Enter" is only working when you focus on the search-box which require a click on the mouse before the "Enter"

Comment: You'll type something in the input right? from the keyboard? As you type, you can just press enter and search no need to go to the mouse again @dWinder  Unless you use an on screen keyboard.....

Comment: No - the search word already typed-in, then just by one click (without touching the keyboard) I could refresh the search. I know I can also do it by clicking the chrome refresh button - but that not a reason to remove this button

Comment: Yeah, that's not the reason to remove it. I use the mouse rarely because it requires hand movements that are quite exhausting. You can also reload using CTRL + R and I'm sure you are aware of that. They should bring it back because for people who don't have a keyboard and are using the on-screen keyboard. Just like windows has ease of access options for people without a keyboard or a mouse. @dWinder

Answer (score -5):

This is not a bug, but rather the intended design. There *is* a search icon, but it's not clickable, and it's on the left side of the search box, not the right side. I don't recall ever seeing a blue magnifying glass, at least not for a long, long time. Certainly not one that was clickable.

You may be confusing the existing (grey) magnifying glass with the still-extant "Search" button from the actual Search Results page (where you'd need to be in order to "refresh" a search, e.g. search a second time):

[image: Search button on the Search Results page]

Comment: After consulting the Wayback Machine, it does not appear that there was ever a clickable "submit query" element in that form.

Comment: there certainly had been an button in the search bar: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/320679/size-of-the-search-textbox-in-the-top-bar-is-increased-suddenly-on-all-the-sites and I disagree this is intended design. This is a regression.  / cc @TinyGiant

Comment: I am pretty sure there was - I used to refresh the search by clicking it with the mouse (so I don't need to use the keyboard). I am not talking about the search black rectangle - it was there last week for sure

Comment: @rene While arguably a regression, it's pretty clearly an *intentional* design change, so not a [meta-tag:bug].

Comment: @rene sorry, I started looking _before_ the redesign assuming that this has been the way it is since the redesign. I guess that's what happens when you assume. Prior to the redesign there was no clickable "submit query" element in that form.

Comment: well, it will make [text browser support](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/384767/578411) even harder but it looks like the UX people have it their way. Too bad.

Comment: It may be intentional but it's still a bug.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I guess we define bug differently then. I consider a bug to be something unexpected or unintentional. An intentional change by definition can never be a bug.

Comment: @TylerH A bug is something that doesn't work properly, be it as compared to expectations or as compared to usability & accessibility conventions/standards. If SE were to deliberately disable all keyboard input to their websites, that would still be a bug.

Comment: @TylerH ^ I don't _really_ believe this, but I'm deliberately pushing the definition a little in order to show _outrage_ because in this case I think it's warranted. ;)

Comment: I noticed that the search button (`form#search input[type=search]`) disappeared about 26 hours ago. To confirm that, I checked the internet archive ([web.archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20191101000000*/stackoverflow.com)), and it says the search button disappeared on June 11, 2019 between [14:14:09](https://web.archive.org/web/20190611141409/https://stackoverflow.com/) and [20:16:13](https://web.archive.org/web/20190611201613/https://stackoverflow.com/).  This means that it actually disappeared 30-36 hours ago. The button was always clickable with a script, but only visible on focus.

Comment: It's not a bug if intended, but it does present a UX issue for the minority that benefits from a clickable search button. (I'm totally OK with it being gone, though.)